# Segurança de um site

Tags: html, segurança, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria de tirar umas dúvidas. Meu site está protegido contra ataques SQL Injection pois estou usando MysQLi com bind além de scripts externos contra proteção deste problema. E o certificado HTTPS está ativado e funcional. Agora a pergunta que me surge: tem como meu site ser atacado de outra forma? Rodei um programa para verificar brechas chamado **OWASP Zed attack** e ele me retornou alguns alertas de falhas como *XSS Header protection* e algumas coisas que era mais voltada pro Internet Explorer. Então a pergunta que fica, tem como meu site sofrer algum tipo de ataque ou ser sujeito a falhas? Se sim, poderiam me mandar arquivos ou conteúdos para eu estudar? Ficaria super agradecido.

Obrigado pelo seu tempo e desculpe qualquer coisa. Boa noite.

Comment: Nenhum sistema está 100% de falhas ou ataques. Recomendo estes sites: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page **e** https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Não podes deixar de fora validação de inputs, se estás à espera de um input númerico então o que acontece se enviar string? Se está à espera de string com 60 chars, o que acontece se enviar uma com 21442412 chars? etc.. o O @ValdeirPsr, deixou boas refs e podes começar por aí

Comment: Olá. A validação de inputs já foi bem trabalhada. Obrigado pelos comentários

Answer (score 0):

Beleza amigo, essa é uma pergunta que só tem uma resposta "seu site nunca estará totalmente protegido" ele pode estar dificultando os tipos de ataque como fez protegendo dos ataques de SQL Injection, mas como por exemplo como tem um site ele tem um limite de conexões suportáveis no qual se você não definir a quantidade de conexões máximas permitidas (o que em muitos sites não é feito) um simples ataque Dos ou DDos pode deixar seu site fora do ar, isso poder ser evitado se em seu projeto determinar a quantidade máxima se conexões permitidas.

Comment: No caso, eu já estou protegido contra ataques DDoS também pois meu site está hospedado na empresa OVH, uma host de ponta quando se fala de ataques DDoS

Comment: @Strepk DDoS só se evita com tratamento no servidor, e não na aplicação

Comment: Sim, o servidor é da OVH, da uma olhada lá no Google dps. Mas eu queria saber mesmo era na aplicação em questão de invasão e coisas do tipo, não sobre DDoS em si.